# Reading windows logs using jna

Tags: jna

## I am getting an exception while reading windows logs using jna

Following is the program, I am using to read the logs. I took this program from another post.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    HANDLE h = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenEventLog(null, "Application");
    IntByReference pnBytesRead = new IntByReference();
    IntByReference pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded = new IntByReference();

    IntByReference pOldestRecord = new IntByReference();
    assertTrue(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.GetOldestEventLogRecord(h,  pOldestRecord));
    int dwRecord = pOldestRecord.getValue();
    System.out.println("OLD: " + dwRecord);
    IntByReference pRecordCount = new IntByReference();
    assertTrue(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(h, pRecordCount));
    int dwRecordCnt = pRecordCount.getValue();
    System.out.println("CNT: " + dwRecordCnt);

    int bufSize = 0x7ffff; //(r.size()) * 2048;
    Memory buffer = new Memory(bufSize);
    int rc = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.ReadEventLog(h, 
            WinNT.EVENTLOG_SEEK_READ  /*
            | WinNT.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ */ 
            | WinNT.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ /*
            | WinNT.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ*/
            , 
            dwRecord, buffer, 
            bufSize, 
            pnBytesRead, 
            pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded)) {

        rc = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
        if (rc == W32Errors.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            break;
        }        

        int dwRead = pnBytesRead.getValue();
        Pointer pevlr = buffer;

        while (dwRead > 0) 
        {
            cnt++;
            EVENTLOGRECORD record = new EVENTLOGRECORD(pevlr);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(cnt+". " + dwRecord + " Event ID: " + record.EventID.shortValue() + " SID: " + record.UserSidLength);

            dwRecord++;

            // WCHAR SourceName[]
            // WCHAR Computername[]
            {
                ByteBuffer names = pevlr.getByteBuffer(record.size(), 
                        (record.UserSidLength.intValue() != 0 ? record.UserSidOffset.intValue() : record.StringOffset.intValue()) - record.size());
                names.position(0);
                CharBuffer namesBuf = names.asCharBuffer();
                String[] splits = namesBuf.toString().split("\0");
                System.out.println("SOURCE NAME: \n" + splits[0]);
                System.out.println("COMPUTER NAME: \n" + splits[1]);
            }
            // SID   UserSid
            if (record.UserSidLength.intValue() != 0){
                ByteBuffer sid = pevlr.getByteBuffer(record.UserSidOffset.intValue(), record.UserSidLength.intValue());
                sid.position(0);
                //CharBuffer sidBuf = sid.asCharBuffer();
                byte[] dst = new byte[record.UserSidLength.intValue()];
                sid.get(dst);
                System.out.println("SID: \n" + Arrays.toString(dst));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("SID: \nN/A");
            }
            // WCHAR Strings[]
            {
                ByteBuffer strings = pevlr.getByteBuffer(record.StringOffset.intValue(), record.DataOffset.intValue() - record.StringOffset.intValue());
                strings.position(0);
                CharBuffer stringsBuf = strings.asCharBuffer();
                System.out.println("STRINGS["+record.NumStrings.intValue()+"]: \n" + stringsBuf.toString());
            }
            // BYTE  Data[]
            {
                ByteBuffer data = pevlr.getByteBuffer(record.DataOffset.intValue(), record.DataLength.intValue());
                data.position(0);
                CharBuffer dataBuf = data.asCharBuffer();
                System.out.println("DATA: \n" + dataBuf.toString());
            }
            // CHAR  Pad[]
            // DWORD Length;

            dwRead -= record.Length.intValue();
            pevlr = pevlr.share(record.Length.intValue());
        }
    }
    assertTrue(rc == W32Errors.ERROR_HANDLE_EOF);
    assertTrue(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.CloseEventLog(h));        
}


private static void assertTrue(boolean getOldestEventLogRecord) {

}
```

}

The Exception is as follows :-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.IntegerType.
    <init>(IJZ)V
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORD.<init>(WinDef.java:57)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef$DWORD.<init>(WinDef.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.defaultValue(NativeMappedConverter.java:47)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.<init>(NativeMappedConverter.java:41)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.getInstance(NativeMappedConverter.java:29)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:803)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:254)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:238)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:174)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:163)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$EVENTLOGRECORD.<init>(WinNT.java:1789)
    at Test.main(Test.java:54)
```

Please help me out from the trouble. Thanks a lot in advance. I am new to this great site so, please excuse me for bad explanation

Comment: Version mismatch between your code, jna.jar and/or platform.jar.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Could you please tell me which version I should use. I have been stuck for five days and trying to resolve it but not yet succeded

Comment: 3.5.1 is available from the [maven repository](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.5.1/).  If you're using NetBeans or some such which includes a different version of JNA, you should [use that version instead](http://aboulton.blogspot.com/2012/07/netbeans-and-java-native-access.html), or build and run standalone.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sir I used the 3.5.1 version of jna but it is still giving the same error at the same place, in fact at 'EVENTLOGRECORD record = new EVENTLOGRECORD(pevlr);' I am using jdk1.6, platform3.4.0. and jna3.5.1.jar.Please give me some more suggestions...

Comment: I am facing same issue even the version of jna and platform both are same.
I am running at jna-4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use different versions of platform.jar and jna.jar.  *That* is what is causing your error.  Both are distributed together, so I don't understand why you're using one version of one with a different version of the other.